# python - removing whitespaces not working - encoding issue?

Tags: python, character-encoding, strip

I have a dataset which contains data scraped from a real estate agency.
I want to clean the variables from special characters (€, m², etc), remove whitespaces and convert them into integers.
For instance I have these for the price (Prix de vente) and size (Surface habitable):

[image]

I manage to strip the "€" from the price variable with the following:

```
data["Prix de vente"] = data["Prix de vente"].str.strip("€")
```

However none of these two techniques work to remove the whitespaces

```
data["Prix de vente"] = data["Prix de vente"].str.strip() 
data["Prix de vente"] = data["Prix de vente"].replace(" ","")
```

I keep having:

```
      540 000
      900 000
      890 000
      900 000
      900 000
      ...
```

I have a feeling this is due to the way my data is encoded. Would that be the issue? And if so, how do I deal with it?
I'm using a jupyter notebook.

Comment: It's rather difficult to reproduce that behavior with only an image of the data... Can you provide the contents of a saved csv file that can be copy/pasted?

Comment: It looks like your numbers might actually be two separate strings - maybe try concatenating them?

Comment: The replace is ok, but you need to copy the space character from your table: it is not the standard space, but a non-breaking space (you should not break line between digts, and possibly between unit and number).

Comment: @FlyingTeller, happy to send an example, but I don't know how? It seems like we can't share datasets through stackoverflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
data["Prix de vente"] = data["Prix de vente"].str.replace("\s","", regex=True)
```

Matching `"\s"` combined with `regex=True` instead of `" "` makes sure to match not only regular spaces but [any whitespace character](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters)

**More background:**

Your first approach

```
data["Prix de vente"] = data["Prix de vente"].str.strip()
```

does not work, since [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) only removes leading and trailing characters.

Your second approach

```
data["Prix de vente"] = data["Prix de vente"].replace(" ","")
```

does not work, since it is using not str.replace, but [pd.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), which only replaces exact matches of values (e.g. "900 000").

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work niether. I keep having that whitespace...

Comment: Then indeed you have a non-standard space, you can try by matching "\s" for all whitespaces. I adjusted the answer

Comment: Thank you !! works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

There is the usual way (but ugly):

```
data["Prix de vente"] = "".join(data["Prix de vente"].str.split())
```

How it works?

The string method `split()` will split the string on *white spaces*. Generic *white spaces*, so not just `" "`, but also `"\t"`, `"\u00a0"`, etc.
Then you join again the substrings, without any spaces.
So you remove the spaces (in not a much intuitive way, but it such method is frequently used, sometimes just to normalize spaces).

Why this works and but not your solution?

Some locales write numbers and currencies with NBSP (non breaking space, \u00A0), instead of standard spaces, which is more sensible (avoiding line break bewteen digit groups). Also some formatters may use other kind of spaces (e.g. small spaces) for such cases, so the solution should care about handling all different white spaces.